# jQuery and memory leak in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, memory-leaks

We have this Javascript function for repeatedly refreshing part of page:

```
        function refreshScreen() {
            var href = document.location.href;
            var idx = href.indexOf('?');
            $jQ.get(href.substring(0, (idx > 0 ? idx : href.length)) + '?random=' + Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000000)+1), function(data) {
                $jQ('#mainTable').replaceWith($jQ(data).find('#mainTable'));
            });
        }
        $jQ(document).ready(function() {
            if ($jQ('#mainTable').is('.refresh')) {
                window.setInterval(refreshScreen, 10000);
            }
        });
```

It works in all browsers but in IE8 it causes memory leak (cca 30MB/min). We have tried jQuery 1.8.3. and 1.10.1 but with the same result. Thanks in advance for a answer.

Comment: I'm guessing that #mainTable is of substantial size. If I was doing something like this, I would go out of my way to update only those table rows that have changed. This would typically make the code more complex, maybe significantly so, and may not kill the memory leak completely, but could make it much less leaky.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
....
$jQ.get(href.substring(0, (idx > 0 ? idx : href.length)) + '?random=' + Math.floor((Math.random()*1000000000)+1),  replaceWithData });
....

function replaceWithData(data){
 $jQ('#mainTable').replaceWith($jQ(data).find('#mainTable'));
}
```

For one of my projects, I deleted the "closures" because caused memory leaks (circular reference).

see : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12231/Memory-Leakage-in-Internet-Explorer-revisited